# Dequeue Oracle AQ with ODP.NET With MSGID

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, advanced-queuing

I am  trying to Dequeue a Message from oracle AQ using ODP.NET by  service

I have two conditions

1. MessageID of the Of the Record in Queue table to be dequeued will be provided by
   the Service
2. Once the Service Dequeue the message  that record should not be available for other instances of services ,Means it should be locked till transaction is committed or transaction expires

Issue :

1. DequeueOptions MsgID not Recognising my MSGID
2. Cannot find how to lock other instances from dequeuing same msg ID

And My Queue is like

```
BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(
     Queue_table        => '"DEVENV1_CUSTOM"."INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE"',
     Queue_payload_type => '"DEVENV1_CUSTOM"."TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE"',
     Sort_list          => 'ENQ_TIME',
     Compatible         => '10.0.0',
     primary_instance   => 3,
     secondary_instance => 2);
  END;
```

Can somebody suggest me a way to pass msgid of record to be dequeued from queue and how to lock them from others accessing it till commit or time out

```
public static void DequeueMessage(string MessageID)
        {
            // Create connection
            string constr = "my constring";
            Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(constr);
            // Create queue
            OracleAQQueue queue = new OracleAQQueue("DEVENV1_CUSTOM.INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE_Q", con);
            try
            {
                // Open connection
                con.Open();     
                // Begin txn for enqueue
                Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleTransaction txn = con.BeginTransaction();
                // Prepare to Dequeue
                queue.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit;

                queue.DequeueOptions.Wait = 10;

                queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Locked;

                // Set message type for the queue
                queue.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;

                queue.UdtTypeName = "TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE";        

                queue.DequeueOptions.MessageId = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("A0CB9F328889420D8F0C8A62BF38B454");

                // Dequeue message
                OracleAQMessage deqMsg = queue.Dequeue();

                TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE data = (TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE)deqMsg.Payload;

                // Dequeue txn commit
                txn.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
               
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close/Dispose objects

                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think you are doing it right. `If LOCKED is specified, then the message is dequeued with a write lock that lasts for the duration of the transaction`  Is it not behaving like that ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez yes its locked but if i call another instance of service it also dequeue the same record

Comment: Also after committing it is not removed from QueueTable

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the the byte array returned by the Oracle and byte array created by .net are different (read about little Endian and Big Endian if you are intereseted )

so i solved the issue by directly casting the array from oracle and  used it for Dequeue

```
  OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand("Select MSGID  from INTEGRATION_MSG_QUEUE where msgid='B85439241C9241A4A6B1869F08F382E7'", con);
            var K=  oracleCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            Byte[] rawBytesFromOracle =K as byte[];
           


            // Begin txn for enqueue
            Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleTransaction txn = con.BeginTransaction();
            // Prepare to Dequeue
            queue.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit;

            queue.DequeueOptions.Wait = 10;

            queue.DequeueOptions.DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Locked;

            queue.DequeueOptions.MessageId = rawBytesFromOracle;


            // Set message type for the queue
            queue.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;

            queue.UdtTypeName = "TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE";


            Console.WriteLine("DeQueueing ............ ");

            // Dequeue message
            OracleAQMessage deqMsg = queue.Dequeue();

            TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE data = (TRIGGER_AUDIT_TYPE)deqMsg.Payload;

            Console.WriteLine("Dequeued message...." + data.CMESSAGEBODY );
```